# How do I determine if a date was within a week range?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have a record with a `created_at` field populated. What I want to do is know if that `created_at` was created 1-2 weeks ago, meaning, days 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, not 1-7 or 15+.

Given that I can't query for this in SQL, what's the best Rails way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 ((2.weeks.ago)..(1.week.ago)).cover?(record.created_at)
```

Assuming 2 weeks ago was the 13th of August, 1 week ago is the 20th of August and the record's `created_at` attribute lies somewhere in the middle, this will return `true`.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but the weeks ago need to be based on the record.created_at

Comment: FYI, that loops w a console error "/Users/X/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:332: warning: Time#succ is obsolete; use time + 1"

Comment: Please explain your question better. Clearly there is a lot of ambiguity in your original question. Why do you want to see if the created_at is within 1-2 weeks before the created at?

Comment: `include?` is deprecated, now it is recommended to use `cover?` instead, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659668/9985521)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on Ruby 2.0.0, Rails 4.0

```
Record.created_at.between?(((Date.today - 14.days).beginning_of_day),(Date.today.end_of_day))
```

Comment: Thanks, but per the Q above, Im not querying the database. I already have a record with .created_at

Answer (score 1):

You could use a range

```
Range.new((Date.today-14.days), 
   (Date.today-7.days)) === record.created_at
```

Adjust the range arugments depending on your meaning of two weeks ago.

**EDIT:** 
The one liner is a bit terse. To break it down.

```
start_date = (Date.today - 14.days)
end_date = (Date.today - 7.days)

# Now start_date is 2 weeks ago, and end_date is 1 week ago.
#   Test if created_at falls within this range
Range.new(start_date.to_date, end_date.to_date) === record.created_at
```

Comment: Something strange there. The range => Mon, 12 Aug 2013..Mon, 02 Sep 2013... And my created_at = > c.created_at.to_date
 => Mon, 26 Aug 2013  --- This doesn't make sense as the line above is returning true.

Comment: Shouldn't it return true? The 26th of august is between the 12th of August and the 2nd of september.

Comment: I think I see the problem, I added a +7.days instead of -7.days. Sorry about that. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks, but I need the 2-3 week range to be based off when the record.created_at so I know if this user was created 2-3 weeks ago...

Comment: 2-3 week range, or 1-2 week range?

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by "based on created_at" it seems like this what you asked for. When you say "ago" do you not mean 1-2 weeks before now?

Answer (score 1):

## Updated answer for rails 7.0

[Release Notes - Active Support Removals](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/7_0_release_notes.html#active-support-removals)

> Remove deprecated support to use Range#include? to check the inclusion of a value in a date time range is deprecated.

It's now recommended to use the [cover?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Range/cover%3F) method.

For example:

```
((2.weeks.ago)..(1.week.ago)).cover?(record.created_at)
```